# Syntax of strongly typed enums wrongly implemented?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, ctp

I'm currently testing the November CTP for Visual Studio 2012 and came across an interesting problem: Is it mandated by the standard that for strongly typed enumerations the `enum` and `struct`/`class` keywords have to be in the same line or is that an error in the implementation that should be reported to Microsoft?

This compiles:

```
enum struct name : type { ...
```

This does not (C2332)

```
enum
struct name : type { ...
```

**EDIT:** as James suggested this is a bug in the implementation and was reported to [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773118/bug-in-implementation-of-strongly-typed-enums)

Comment: `enum class/struct` doesn't require the NovCTP. So does this happen on the pure VC2012 release?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Just tried, the bug seems to be also in the RTM version of the compiler!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is undoubtedly a bug.  Newlines are not significant after preprocessing.

This is tracked by the following issue on Microsoft Connect  (To the OP:  Thank you for opening this bug.):

> [Bug in implementation of strongly typed enums](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773118/bug-in-implementation-of-strongly-typed-enums)

If this bug is important to you, please upvote it on Microsoft Connect.  Note that there is a trivial workaround:  don't place a newline between the `enum` and `struct` keywords.

Comment: Just as I expected. I filed a bug report.

Comment: Would you post a link here to the bug, for future readers of this question? (And so I can track it.)  Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, I added the link to the question.

Comment: James, you're awesome. The way you actively track and file bugs is very helpful. Let me know when you need help fixing them. ;)